# The question on religiosity and genetics

Tags: discussion

The question [Is religiosity specialized enough to have its own genes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8128/is-religiosity-specialized-enough-to-have-its-own-genes) has been closed. I think this is a mistake.

The question was closed as a duplicate of [Are human beings naturally predisposed to believe in God?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/are-human-beings-naturally-predisposed-to-believe-in-god)

That question is specific to whether or not humans have a predisposition to believe in a divine entity. It is not about religiosity in general.

The question currently closed seems to me to be questioning if religiosity could have any genetic basis, essentially if it is more than just a construct.

The answers to the question on humans having a predisposition to believe in god do not apply to this question, and so it is not a duplicate.

Likewise, issues of religiosity not related to divine entity such as [brand religiosity](http://articles.cnn.com/2011-05-19/tech/apple.religion_1_apple-store-apple-employees-brains?_s=PM:TECH) or [science as a religion](http://www.thehumanist.org/humanist/articles/dawkins.html) would not apply to a question which is specific to a divine entity.

While the question is *closely related*, it is not a *duplicate*.

Please reopen, as I would like to see the question answered.

Comment: The author of the question didn't complain about the closing, so the answer in the duplicate seems to satisfy him.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that they are not exactly the same, however the linked claim does not correspond to the question at all.

There is no issue, and nothing in the [underlying paper](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/278/1717/2519) that requires "religiosity" to have a gene, except that children should have similar religiosity to their parents. This basically makes the question off-topic, because it's not about a real claim.

**What the question asks**

> I am skeptical that genes could determine a persons religiosity.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8128/is-religiosity-specialized-enough-to-have-its-own-genes

**What the article says**

> Rowthorn has developed a model that shows that **the genetic components that predispose a person toward religion** are currently “hitchhiking” on the back of the religious cultural practice of high fertility rates. Even if some of the people who are born to religious parents defect from religion and become secular, the religious genes they carry (which encompass other personality traits, such as obedience and conservativism) will still spread throughout society, according to the model’s numerical simulations.

http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/278/1717/2519

Not *determine* but *predispose* - which clearly much less controversial. For example, children are genetically predisposed to imitate their parents.

**What the peer reviewed article really says**

> Religious people nowadays have more children on average than their secular counterparts. **This paper** uses a simple model to explore the evolutionary implications of this difference. It **assumes that** fertility is determined entirely by culture, whereas **subjective predisposition towards religion is influenced by genetic endowment.**

http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/278/1717/2519

So it's a model, based on assumption. There is no explicit claim that the model actually represents reality. It's a "theoretical" and not "experimental" article, if you will.

In short, *nobody is claiming what the question asks*. I've therefored reopened, and closed the question as off-topic.

Comment: That's a good answer, and I now support the closure. If a suitable claim was found, I would guess the question could be re-opened without it being closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell Can't say without the claim - in any case I still think it's a dupe as is.